# Zohar and Sholom

Tags: sources-mekorot, zohar

The Zohar states, *“Hashem **is** Sholom, His **name** is Sholom  and all is **bound** by Sholom.”*

Where does the Zohar say this?

Comment: Please [edit] into the question why you think the Zohar says this.

Comment: @IsaacMoses: Look at the answer below.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I have edited your motivation into the question. Feel free to do so yourself in the future.

Comment: @DoubleAA, why edit a question to make it worse? A motivation that looks dishonest when examined is worse than no motivation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I thought maybe the OP would benefit by seeing what he's actually suggesting. Describing it to him in words has failed thus far repeatedly at being an effective method of education.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I suggest that degrading the quality of part of our repository of Q&A as a means of expressing frustration and teaching someone a lesson is not a path we ought to venture onto.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Can you identify perhaps a non-recursive motivation for the question to be [edit]ed in? Why would you suspect the Zohar says this that you seek its source in the Zohar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from the Zohar on *Vayikra* ([10b](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%99%D7%98)):

> תא חזי קב"ה אקרי שלום הוא שלום ושמיה שלום ואתקשר כלא בשלום

Translation:

> Come and see: The Holy One Blessed be He is called "Shalom" ("Peace"). He is peace, and his name is Peace, and everything is bound in peace.